# How to join index and index and make it to the new list - python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code like this:

```
x = []
for fitur in self.fiturs:
    x.append(fitur[0])
a = [x , rpxy_list]
join = zip(*a)
print join
```

and in the self.fiturs is:

```
F1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1
F2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1
F3,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1
F4,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0
F5,14,24,22,22,22,16,18,19,26,22
F6,8.0625,6.2,6.2609,6.6818,6.2174,6.3333,7.85,6.0833,6.9655,6.9167
F7,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
F8,1,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0
F9,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
F10,8,4,3,3,3,6,8,5,8,4
F11,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
F12,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1
```

In the **rpxt_list** is the float

and the output of the program is:

```
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\Skripsi\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Skripsi/coba.py
[('F1', 0.2182178902359924), ('F1', 0.2182178902359924), ('F2', 0.408248290463863), ('F3', 0.2), ('F4', 0.408248290463863), ('F5', 0.37142857142857144), ('F6', 0.5053765608632352), ('F7', 0.5), ('F8', 0.6201736729460423), ('F9', 0.2182178902359924), ('F10', 0.6864064729836441), ('F11', 0.5), ('F12', 0.0), ('F13', 0), ('F14', 0), ('F15', 0), ('F16', 0), ('F17', 0), ('F18', 0), ('F19', 0), ('F20', 0), ('F21', 0), ('F22', 0), ('F23', 0.2672612419124244), ('F24', 0.4364357804719848), ('F25', 0), ('F26', 0), ('F27', 0), ('F28', 0), ('F29', 0), ('F30', 0), ('F31', 0), ('F32', 0), ('F33', 0), ('F34', 0), ('F35', 0), ('F36', 0), ('F37', 0.7808688094430304)]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And I just want the output like this:

```
['F1', 0.2182178902359924]
['F2', 0.408248290463863]
etc
```

What should i do with my code?

Comment: Show the code that prints the output

Comment: `for pair in join: print(list(pair))`

Comment: Shouldn't use `join` as a variable name, as it overrides a builtin method.

Comment: it's up there, 'the output of program' @NiVeR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
join = [('F1', 0.2182178902359924), ('F1', 0.2182178902359924), ('F2', 0.408248290463863), ('F3', 0.2), ('F4', 0.408248290463863), ('F5', 0.37142857142857144), ('F6', 0.5053765608632352), ('F7', 0.5), ('F8', 0.6201736729460423), ('F9', 0.2182178902359924), ('F10', 0.6864064729836441), ('F11', 0.5), ('F12', 0.0), ('F13', 0), ('F14', 0), ('F15', 0), ('F16', 0), ('F17', 0), ('F18', 0), ('F19', 0), ('F20', 0), ('F21', 0), ('F22', 0), ('F23', 0.2672612419124244), ('F24', 0.4364357804719848), ('F25', 0), ('F26', 0), ('F27', 0), ('F28', 0), ('F29', 0), ('F30', 0), ('F31', 0), ('F32', 0), ('F33', 0), ('F34', 0), ('F35', 0), ('F36', 0), ('F37', 0.7808688094430304)]
with open('filename.csv','wb') as file:
    for pair in join:
        file.write(pair)
        file.write('\n')
```

Because you are using 'join' as a variable name, the method join will be overwritten and cannot be used in your code unless you delete the variable 'join' again by:

```
del join
```

Comment: Just don't use `join` as a name in the first place.

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: @FachrulRozySaputraR Added the code for writing in a file. Is this your answer?

Comment: Actually thats my question, i tried writing in csv but the program only write the first line 'F1', 0.2182, i am sorry for always asking because i'm newbie in python @HugodeHeer btw thank you so much for the help

Comment: @FachrulRozySaputraR No problem! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

The zip function returns an iterator of tuples so that is why you are getting tuples instead of lists. If you just want you output to be the lists  then why not just print a and leave out the join line?

```
x = []
for fitur in self.fiturs:
    x.append(fitur[0])
a = [x , rpxy_list]
print(a)
```